sumifs with a criteria
Here is my data.
iris.dt<-as.data.table(iris);

And this is exactly what I want, and it works fine.
iris.dt[,Sum.Petal.Width := c(sum(Petal.Width),rep(0, .N - 1)), by = Species];

Output to verify:

So what it does is create a new column to the right of name Sum.Petal.Width which is a sum on  Petal.Width and the sum is displayed on the first iteration of the category of Species while others are set to zero.
problem is:
On a large data set it is slow, I need something which is faster. maybe there exist a better way of doing it. or if I am doing it wrong.
I need the code only using data.table package.

I don't see anything here I would consider slow. I suggest including code to build a data set that is more representative of your actual data so you can demonstrate the slowness of your current solution.

I suspect calling c() for every group is causing a slowdown. Here is one way to avoid it:
iris.dt[, Sum.Petal.Width := 0]
iris.dt[which(rowid(Species) == 1L), 
        Sum.Petal.Width := iris.dt[, sum(Petal.Width), by = Species
                                   ][.SD, on = "Species", V1]]

It seems that using rowid() to find the first observation per group is still not optimal. On some test data the following (collapse) solution is faster:
iris.dt[collapse::fmatch(seq_len(nlevels(Species)), Species), 
        Sum.Petal.Width := iris.dt[, sum(Petal.Width), by = Species
                                   ][.SD, on = "Species", V1]]

Benchmarks:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  op = {
    iris.dt[,Sum.Petal.Width := c(sum(Petal.Width),rep(0, .N - 1)), by = Species]
  },
  sb = {
    iris.dt[, Sum.Petal.Width := 0]
    iris.dt[which(rowid(Species) == 1L), 
            Sum.Petal.Width := iris.dt[, sum(Petal.Width), by = Species
                                       ][.SD, on = "Species", V1]]
  },
  sbclps = {
    iris.dt[, Sum.Petal.Width := 0]
    iris.dt[collapse::fmatch(seq_len(nlevels(Species)), Species), 
            Sum.Petal.Width := iris.dt[, sum(Petal.Width), by = Species
                                       ][.SD, on = "Species", V1]]
  },
  setup = {
    n <- 5e7L
    iris.dt <- data.table(
      Petal.Width = sample(iris$Petal.Width, size = n, replace = TRUE),
      Species = factor(sample(1:3000, size = n, replace = TRUE))
    )
  },
  times = 3L
)
# Unit: seconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#      op 2.626192 2.674945 2.792849 2.723698 2.876178 3.028659     3
#      sb 1.874173 1.901939 2.092839 1.929705 2.202172 2.474640     3
#  sbclps 1.336393 1.340518 1.356910 1.344643 1.367168 1.389693     3

